# setScreenname() only fires after logEvent()

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I try to use Firebase to track my app. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class Section1121: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        Analytics.setScreenName("Screen1.1.2.1", screenClass: "Section1121")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventAddToCart, parameters: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

I expect following order:
1: default `screen_view` event fires, without changing screen name
2: `setScreenname` fires and changes the screen name
3: `logevent` fires, sending `add_to_cart` event with new screen name

But actual order on debug view is 1 -> 3 -> 2, and `add_to_cart` is logged without new screen name.
Here's the [screenshot of debug view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZe3s.png).

In the code `setScreenname` is definitely before `logEvent`, but why the firing order has changed?
Can I make it fire before `logEvent`?

Comment: setScreenName should be called in viewDidAppear: instead of loadView: the screen should be visible to users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following adbitx's advice, I moved `setScreenName` to `viewDidAppear` just before `logEvent`, and the code seems to work properly.